# Why isn't the website in the profile page clickable?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, hyperlinks

We can click the website mentioned by the users in their profile page. They can enter anything that [should](https://stackoverflow.com/users/756941/nazik) be [clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2556654/obiemd5).

But, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2559479/ravi-allam) profile page, the website link is not clickable. Why not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is a [new users restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user). You need to gain 10 reputation to remove new users restrictions.

Answer (score 9):

The link is not an actual link until you have a little rep (10).  It's an intentional behavior to prevent spam.

Comment: status-by-design...

Comment: @Azik oops you're right...thought it had a support and not bug tag, updated.

Comment: @NickCraver - I can't find any description regarding website doesn't contain link in [New usres](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) privileges page. AFAIK it was in old pages.

Comment: @hims056, yes this info should be added on new users previleges.